# Angular 15: ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications

Tags: angular, webpack

(Note that this is a development environment, not a production build. It might not appear in production, or just go to the console.)

I can't seem to find anything through googling... the closest I get are references to "ResizeObserver - loop limit exceeded". I'm puzzled by this, since it doesn't occur on the other page.

Comment: Do you have the LastPass browser extension installed?  I have now twice encountered clients where this extension triggered this error on a responsive web application.

Comment: I tried installing LastPass chrome extention but could not replicate this error myself :( But we get a ton of these errors from clients - but we don't know why still.